# Why doesn't this function terminate in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am confused why my function `nest` which composes `f` with itself `n` times

```
nest f 0 = id
nest f n = f . nest f (n - 1)
```

never terminates. I would have thought that it would "pattern match" on the case when `n` becomes zero. I am defining it by typing these two lines into GHCI and calling with `nest (+ 1) 2 3` for instance.

Comment: We need more.  How are you defining and loading this function? How are you calling this function?  When I save it as a file, load it with GHCi 8.6.4, and call it as `nest (+1) 3 2` it terminates with `5`.

Comment: Oh interesting. I was pasting into GHCI and calling it just like you with `nest (+1) 3 2`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By typing the function on two separate REPL lines, you are essentially redefining it the second time around, omitting the base case.

The correct way to enter this function into the REPL is:

```
nest f 0 = id; nest f n = f . nest f (n - 1)
```

Alternatively, you can enter multiline mode with the `:{` command, and leave it using `:}`.

Answer (score 6):

When you pasted it into GHCi what you did was define one function of `nest f 0 = id`.  Then you said "ignore that function, I'm replacing it with a new function of the same name where the whole definition is `nest f n = f . nest f (n - 1)`.